# Are $\pi$ and $e^{\pi i \sqrt{d}}$ algebraically independent?

Tags: nt.number-theory, transcendental-number-theory

Let $-d\in\mathbb{N}$ be square-free. Nesterenko (https://doi.org/10.1070/SM1996v187n09ABEH000158) proved that $e^{\pi\sqrt{-d}}$ and $\pi$ are algebraically independent. Is it known whether $e^{\pi\sqrt{-d}}$ and $\pi$ are algebraically independent when, instead, $d\in\mathbb{N}$ is square-free?

Note that, subject to the truth of Schanuel's conjecture, the latter is true by considering the transcendence degree of $\\{\pi i, \pi i\sqrt{d}, e^{\pi i}, e^{\pi i \sqrt{d}}\\}$.

This question was previously posted on math.stackexchange (see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4599969/95131).

Comment: I find it very confusing that in the first sentence you are using $-d$ for a nonnegative number.